Extracting currency of IBKR positions from IBKR api
I found a great block of code to extract the current positions from an Interactive Brokers account through their API. Here is the link to this code:
How do I get my accounts' positions at Interactive Brokers using Python API?
It works super well and I am very happy with it but I have several positions in different currencies. A work around I implemented now is to map a dictionary like this:
ticker_to_currency = {
    'VOO': 'USD',
    'VXF' : 'EUR'
}

positions['Currency'] = positions['Symbol'].map(ticker_to_currency)


However, I am wondering if there is a more robust solution in which the currency can just be extracted straight from the API.

The currency is in the contract object.
from ibapi import wrapper
from ibapi.client import EClient
from ibapi.contract import *
from ibapi.common import *

import pandas as pd

class Get_All_Positions(wrapper.EWrapper, EClient):

    def __init__(self):
        wrapper.EWrapper.__init__(self)
        EClient.__init__(self, wrapper=self)
        self.positions = pd.DataFrame([], columns = ['secType','currency', 'quantity', 'average_cost'] )

    def nextValidId(self, orderId:int):
        self.nextValidOrderId = orderId
        self.reqPositions()

    def position(self, account: str, contract: Contract, position: float, avgCost: float):
        self.positions.loc[contract.symbol]=contract.secType,contract.currency,position,avgCost

    def positionEnd(self):
        print('end get positions')
        self.disconnect()
        print(self.positions)
        
    def error(self, reqId:TickerId, errorCode:int, errorString:str, ):
        print("Error. Id: " , reqId, " Code: " , errorCode , " Msg: " , errorString)

tws_port = 7497
IB_API=Get_All_Positions()
IB_API.connect("127.0.0.1", tws_port, clientId=123)
IB_API.run()


Thank you very much! I tried something like this but couldn't get it right but this is awesome. Is there somewhere where I can find what information is accessible from the contracts and how to do it? The documentation is not so great from IBKR...

https://ibkrcampus.com/ibkr-api-page/twsapi-doc/#contracts
